# Overimpose several plot on increasingly small grid

Tags: plotting

I would like to produce a single plot of a function defined over discrete points in [-1,1] as I increase the number of points while shrinking the distance.

```
f[x_,en_]:= -x^2;
data = Table[f[x,en],{en,10,50,10},{x,-1,1,2/en}]
ListPlot[data]
```

[image]

This is almost what I want, I get all the different run of `f` plotted with nice color, but the x-axis runs from 0 to 50 instead of going from -1 and 1.

I can obtain something closer to what I want if I do

```
data = Table[DiscretePlot[f[x,en],{x,-1,1,2/en}],{en,10,50,10}];
Show[data, PlotRange -> All]
```

but in this case all plots have the same color and are hard to distinguish

[image]

Comment: `data = Table[{x,f[x,en]},{en,10,50,10},{x,-1,1,2/en}]; ListPlot[data]`?

Comment: Almost, but not quite. I am now getting the color of the plot based on the x-coordinate (instead of it being based on en).

Comment: Ah no ok, got it!

Comment: Just add a DataRange -> {-1, 1} option to your ListPlot command